# How to get friendly domain name from ip address in python?

Tags: sockets, networking, dns

I am a networking and python novice.
I am going to get domain names from IP addresses and vice versa.
Here is my code snippet, which is very famous on stackoverflow.com.

```py
import socket
print(socket.gethostbyname('stackoverflow.com')) #151.101.65.69
print(socket.gethostbyaddr('151.101.65.69')) #error
```

```
151.101.65.69
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    socket.gethostbyaddr("151.101.129.69")
socket.herror: [Errno 11004] host not found
```

In case of google.com I get this result:

```py
import socket
print(socket.gethostbyname("google.com")) #'142.251.43.14'
print(socket.gethostbyaddr("142.251.43.14")) #('tsa03s08-in-f14.1e100.net', [], ['142.251.43.14'])
```

The output as

```
'142.251.43.14'
('tsa03s08-in-f14.1e100.net', [], ['142.251.43.14'])
```

I want to get a friendly domain name like "stackoverflow.com" and "google.com".
Is there anyone who has a similar experience to me?

Comment: It is absolutely not required that all IP addresses have `PTR` records mapping them back to names. And even if they do, they may not match the forward resolution.

Comment: @tkius123 what you are asking for is simply not how the DNS system works. You usually can't get back to the original domain name from an IP. That is not how DNS `PTR` records are configured.